# React Native, Expo, ExpoKit - Is there way to use default native camera app of device?

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, expo

I found that there is no way to use (call) default native Android camera app to take picture and return it back into app in Expo managed project.

What about clean React Native project or Project with ExpoKit? Is there way to use just Android's camera instead of writing your own?

Same question with Gallery of images to pick